# Apache Server failing to start when Secfilter engine is on

Tags: apache, mod-security

I'm new to mod_security and i have installed the same on the apache server . When i add a rule `SecFilterEngine On`, in `modsecurity.conf` the server is unable to restart.

If I comment `SecFilterEngine On` and add another rule

`SecAuditLog C:\Server\apache2\logs\mod_security.log`

I'm able to start the server and the security log file  is created successfully in the path mentioned.I want the filter engine to turn on as i need to add filtering rules.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.The apache server is installed on an windows 7 machine and the pastebin links for the `error.log,httpd.conf,modsecurity.conf` are given below.

1. [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/uKgamTbw)
2. [modsecurity.conf](http://pastebin.com/kxahfqSC)
3. [error.log](http://pastebin.com/zGnP8iip)

Comment: Any answer for the question ?